# Repeat rows in Google Sheets based in the number of unique column values

Tags: google-sheets

I have this table:

[image]

I need to create a timeframe model of it, in a day by day view but with one line for each `Client`, so it gets to look like this:

[image]

Number of clients may change with time, so it should somehow dynamically check the unique items in the `Client` column (`UNIQUE(A2:A)` would solve that) and use the number of unique clients to create the date repetitions and client repetitions per date.

[Sample sheet here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14u7fNz2kO-gjPBxZBly4RQhII_NBSXBzisoZF09VUoE/edit#gid=0)

Is there a way out of that?

Comment: Your sheet is currently set to "View only." Please change the permissions to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: Please make a copy, if everyone has edition authorization it will get quite confusing.

Comment: Keep in mind that those who contribute here are volunteers spending our own free time to help people. I do not like to add spreadsheets to my own Drive if they are not for my own projects or those of my regular clients. And creating a solution in a separate sheet and then explaining that solution sight-unseen to you would take far longer than is reasonable.

Comment: I've had this post and your spreadsheet up in a separate browser window since yesterday, in case you responded by opening the sheet or adding me as editor. I see you have not yet done that, nor responded to Sergey below. I'll keep your material open another 12 hours to see if you've opened access to the sheet; otherwise, I'll assume you no longer want the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think your data can be converted using this formula

`=ArrayFormula(query(split(split(FLATTEN(A:A&""&SUBSTITUTE(C1:D1;"Date of ";"")&""&C:D&"*");"*");"");"select Col3, Col1, count(Col1) where Col3 is not null group by Col3, Col1 pivot Col2 order by Col3 label Col1'Client', Col3'Date'"))`

[image]